# Angular Routing Issue with .war file in jboss server using maven build

Tags: java, angular, maven, jboss, ejb

I am creating a .war file and deploying in jboss server which is getting deployed 
     successful. While I hit the url: http://localhost:8080/pickingorder It successfully redirect to index page but when I refresh the page or click to go to perform any other task the angular component doesn't loads. In short angular routing is somehow not working. Any help appreciated thanks in advance.

Attaching my Project structure screenshot ..

[image]

web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>/dist/client/index.html</welcome-file>
          </welcome-file-list>
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
        <context-root>pickingorder</context-root>
    </jboss-web>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
      imports:
        [
          RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            initialNavigation: 'enabled', useHash: true, onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
          })
        ],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

index.html

```
<base href="/pickingorder/dist/client/">
```

pom.xml

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the option [SkipLocationChange](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#skipLocationChange) on your router links? You could also experiment with different base urls, e.g. an empty one `<base href="">`.

Comment: @fridoo I didn't try with SkpLocationChange but yes i did some experiment with different url stiil it wasn't work.

Comment: Well then try if routing works if you use `skipLocationChange` and use `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })` to log the internal router events (without any other settings to minimize possible error sources). Check the router logs and add them to your question here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Finally I found the solution after trying lot of possibilities. I replace "href" tag to "routerLink" as below. Jboss doesn’t understands the routing of Angular therefore ‘Href’ fails But there an way to handle in Angular using routerLink And it worked.

app.component.html : Old Code

```
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="pickingcreate">Create</a></li>
      <li><a href="pickingsearch">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
```

app.component.html : Replaced Code

```
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a routerLink="pickingcreate">Create</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="pickingsearch">Search</a></li>
        </ul>
```